# Passing a Python variable to R using rpy2

Tags: python, mysql, r, rpy2

I have basic R script that performs a GLM on a MySQL dataset. This runs fine using Rscript in bash. However I would like to call it within a python script so I can add it to a loop, I can create the sql statement but I can't seem to pass it to R using rpy2;

```
for word in words:
    sql_scores = "select a.article_id, response, score  from scores as a join profile as b on a.article_id = b.article_id where response in (1,0) and keyword = '%s';" % (word[0])
    robjects.r("library(RMySQL)")
    robjects.r("mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='me', password='xxxx', host='aws.host', dbname='mydb')")
    robjects.r("results = fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, '%s'))") % (sql_scores)
    robjects.r("model <- glm(response ~ score , data=results, family=binomial)")
    robjects.r("summary(model)")
```

If I print sql_scores I can run this fine directly in MySQL. However Python produces this error;

```
Loading required package: DBI
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keyword_searcher.py", line 30, in <module>
    robjects.r("results = fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, '%s'))") % (sql_scores)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 268, in __call__
    p = rinterface.parse(string)
 ValueError: Error while parsing the string.
```

I can't figure out the proper syntax for:

```
robjects.r("results = fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, %s))") % (sql_scores)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes around the `"%s"` and single quotes around the robjects.r string:

```
robjects.r('results = fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, "%s"))') % (sql_scores)
```

or use the `format()` method:

```
robjects.r('fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, {0}))'.format(sql_scores))
```

Comment: I try using .format like this robjects.r('snvs$LoadFile({})'.format(input_file)) but I get the following error:  object 'myresult_file.txt' not found, and when I tried the same approach but not with .format I get no error what do thing is the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can access variables in the R environment with `robjects.globalenv['varname']`.
So an alternative way is:

```
robjects.globalenv['sql_scores'] = sql_scores
robjects.r("results = fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, sql_scores))")
```