# "Error while parsing the string" when using RPy2 and dplyr

Tags: python, r, dplyr, rpy2

I'm using R to do some data manipulation. This is a part of a larger project that is mostly in Python, so I'm not using R directly but RPy2 instead. Things work fine until I get to the dplyr part.

This works:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r

Rcode = '''library(RODBC)
library(dplyr)
# ...
# a bunch of R code that fetches data from SQL Server
# ...'''.format(db_name = 'foo')
print r(Rcode)
```

That gives me the data I want.

But when I try to do some data manipulation with dplyr, like this:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r

Rcode = '''library(RODBC)
library(dplyr)
# ...
# a bunch of R code that fetches data from SQL Server
# ...
myData <- myData
    %>% group_by(someDataField)'''.format(db_name = 'foo')
print r(Rcode)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myScript.py", line 53, in <module>
    print r(Rcode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 268, in __call__
    p = rinterface.parse(string)
ValueError: Error while parsing the string.
```

I've tried escaping the % signs, escaping the > sign, and putting them within quotation marks, but nothing worked.

What am I missing?

I've seen the other questions about the same error (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525027/passing-a-python-variable-to-r-using-rpy2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings)) but they didn't help.

I'm using Python 2.7.10 and RPy2 2.5.6.

Comment: Shouldn't it be print r(R_code) instead of print r(Rcode)?

Comment: Yes - sorry, just fixed it (this is a simplification of the actual code and I mistyped here).

Comment: did you try to do something like :      myData <-  group_by(MyData,someDataField), just to see if the error is really in the %>%  function ?

Comment: That did it. Thanks! You should probably make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Great! I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myData <- group_by(MyData,someDataField)
```

Comment: this explains nothing